# How to Achieve Expose effect in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation, onitemclicklistener, mobile-development

i want to make listView with this type of expose animation when user clicks on any item.

like The first time each user visits the All Apps screen, a semi-transparent overlay appears.

Please suggest me a way or any related example.

sample image:
http://developer.android.com/design/media/help_cling.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library [showcase](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) to highlight. Building a new overlay is simple:

```
new ShowcaseView.Builder(this)
    .setTarget(new ActionViewTarget(this, ActionViewTarget.Type.HOME))
    .setContentTitle("ShowcaseView")
    .setContentText("This is highlighting the Home button")
    .hideOnTouchOutside()
    .build();
```

You can add the library on gradle with:

```
compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.0.0'
```